# Rounded green lines on CoordinatorLayout elements - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Why my CoordinatorLayout round my elements in this strange, green color?
These green lines also appear when the application is built on the device, it only appears when I use CoordinatorLayout to build my button with the text above.

See the image [image: 13]

See my .xml code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFloatingAdicionar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout2"
        app:maxImageSize="56dp"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_addAnuncio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="330dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:text="Anunciar!"
        android:background="@drawable/ronded_corners"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:backgroundTint="@drawable/ronded_corners"`

Comment: Not work it, ronded corners is exclusive to TextView style

Answer (score 0):

The solution was add `android:backgroundTint` with the color of background of elements on my coordinator layout, in my example, i added here:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white">
```